# Difference between Google CalDAV API and Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am a bit confused, is Google CalDAV API for managing domain wide calendars and events? Thus Google Calendar API is just for managing users calendar? Or are they same?

[image]

Comment: The difference is in the protocol. Both let you modify events. Calendar API lets you do more with calendars.

Comment: So is CalDAV is deprecating?

Comment: I haven't heard of anything like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> CalDAV API will become available for whitelisted developers, and will
>   be shut down for other developers on September 16, 2013. Most
>   developers’ use cases are handled well by Google Calendar API, which
>   we recommend using instead.
>     [Official Google Blog](https://googleblog.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html)

Apparently Google backtracked and reinstated CalDAV API since developers were depending on it.

Comment: hi is it possible to integrate my plugin inside google calendar so that i can show my plugin as an option while creating an event in calendar

Comment: @PitchiahNatarajan, no I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

[CalDAV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4791) is a standard API used by multiple calendar providers, while the Google Calendar API is specific to Google Calendar. For basic functionality, either will work, but some features are only available in the Google Calendar API (either because they don't exist in the standard or Google has simply chosen not to implement them there)